# .NET HttpClient: How to set the request method dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, http, webrequest, dotnet-httpclient

How can one use HttpClient and set the method dynamically without having to do something like:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoRequest(string url, HttpContent content, string method)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            switch (method.ToUpper())
            {
                case "POST":
                    response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    break;
                default:
                    response = null;
                    // Unsupported method exception etc.
                    break;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

At the moment it looks like you would have to use:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
```

Comment: You can httprequestmessage and set the method, url and content. Then use send method of httpclient

Comment: Note that you should not `new HttpClient()` per request, or you can exhaust your socket pool at scale.  Use a single static instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HttpRequestMessage` contains constructor taking instance of `HttpMethod` but there is no ready constructor that converts HTTP method string to `HttpMethod`, so you can't avoid that switch (in one form or another).

However you should not have duplicated code under different switch cases, so implementation would be something like this:

```
private HttpMethod CreateHttpMethod(string method)
{
    switch (method.ToUpper())
    {
        case "POST":
            return HttpMethod.Post;
        case "GET":
            return HttpMethod.Get;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoRequest(string url, HttpContent content, string method)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(CreateHttpMethod(method), url)
    {
        Content = content
    };

    return await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

If you don't like that `switch` you could avoid it using Dictionary with method string as a key, however such solution will not be simpler or faster.

Comment: You can also pass in `HttpMethod httpMethod` as a parameter, and then do `new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, url)`

Answer (score 8):

> but there is no ready constructor that converts HTTP method string to HttpMethod

Well that's not true any longer...<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpMethod__ctor_System_String_)</sup>

```
public HttpMethod(string method);
```

Can be used like this:

```
var httpMethod = new HttpMethod(method.ToUpper());
```

Here is working code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace.HttpClient
{
public static class HttpClient
{
    private static readonly System.Net.Http.HttpClient NetHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    static HttpClient()
    {}

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> ExecuteMethod(string targetAbsoluteUrl, string methodName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = null, string content = null, string contentType = null)
    {
        var httpMethod = new HttpMethod(methodName.ToUpper());

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, targetAbsoluteUrl);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType))
        {
            var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
            requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(contentBytes);

            headers = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-type", contentType)
            };
        }

        headers?.ForEach(kvp => { requestMessage.Headers.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value); });

        var response = await NetHttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: the msdn link is not accessible now. Please change to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpMethod__ctor_System_String_

Comment: @ Tsahi Ahser - thanks for editing the resource link!

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core

```
var hc = _hcAccessor.HttpContext;

var hm = new HttpMethod(hc.Request.Method.ToUpper());
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(hm, 'url');
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core later versions:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// Add headers etc...

// Post
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

// Get
response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```